# JpaRepository ManyToMany Deletion problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two models: Events and NotificationUser.

An Event can have many Users and a User can have many Events. I build 2 Models.

Event

```
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Action> actions;
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<NotificationUser> notificationUser;
}
```

NotificationUser

```
public class NotificationUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String email;
    private String name;
}
```

I can create events and I can create users. I can also delete events but, I cannot delete users. I get the following message:

```
update or delete on table "notification_user" violates foreign key constraint "fkjuklqmawfcf1ein89djo7945t" on table "event_notification_user"
  Detail: Key (id)=(12) is still referenced from table "event_notification_user"
```

I don't understand the Annotations to set on the models.

Is there a simple way to handle the relations? I don't want to get my repo locked for some simple stuff like deletions. That's the reason why I use JPARepository.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is the `event_notification_user` table your Event class ? If not can you please show us?

Comment: I got there tables on my postgres event, event_notification_user, notification_user